# Adding or updating dictionary elements using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I need to check if a key exists and accordingly to an add or an update in the dictionary.

```
        if (dict.ContainsKey("Key1"))
            dict["Key1"] = "Value1";
        else
            dict.Add("Key1", "Value1");
```

Can I simplify this using Linq or otherwise?

Comment: You're changing the collection, so no, you should not use Linq for that. If you need to filter or project the sequence, then Linq is appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify your 4 lines of code to this:

```
dict["Key1"] = "Value1";
```

If Key1 doesn't exist in the dictionary it will be added and if it exists the value will be updated. That's what the indexer does. As far as LINQ is concerned I don't see any relation to the question.

Comment: I thought I'd be able to use LINQ to do a select and check if a key exists and decide whether to add an item or update on item.

Comment: @RSharma, what value would LINQ give over what's already there? For example, you already use `ContainsKey`. What is LINQ going to offer that is any more succinct, readable, to the point, etc? LINQ is awesome, don't get me wrong. But you don't need it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not really...linq is a query language and is not intended to mutate data structures.  You can sort of get around this, but you shouldn't consider your code wrong just because it isn't linq.  The only line you could add to the code you posted to 'linq-ify' it would be to change `dict.ContainsKey("Key1")` to `dict.Any(x => x.Key == "Key1")`, but **don't do this** as it will [no doubt be slower](http://byatool.com/lessons/dictionary-index-lookup-vs-contains-key-vs-list-contains-vs-linq-speed-testtexas-tornado-match/).  I actually think Darin's answer is quite elegant and recommend you use it!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("1", "1");
        dict.Add("2", "2");

        var x = dict.Where(q => q.Key == "1");
        if (x.Any())
            dict[x.FirstOrDefault().Key] = "new";
```